# How to get an array to start and begin where you want in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array that starts with a few dozen 0's, proceeds with a few numbers, and than ends with a few more zeros.  I want to make a new array with just the numbers, not the zeros.  it looks something like this

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 245 35635 3563 6346 3465 34 235 46 356 36 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I want to make an array that start like this in matlab

245 35635 3563 6346 3465 34 235 46 356 36

Any ideas.  I tried to use if statements within a loop, but I can only get the zeros at the end to go away

Comment: Try the `find` function.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the series contains middle zeroes?

Answer (score 4):

This should also work:

```
newArray = oldArray(oldArray>0);
```

Comment: Or better `newArray = oldArray(oldArray~=0);`, in case the array has negative numbers

Comment: I always worry about testing for equivalence to zero, just because of the frivolous nature of doubles.

Comment: With zero, it's really only a concern if it is the result of a prior calculatiion (i.e. not a problem when specifically set to zero).

Comment: @Aggieboy, then use `abs(x)-a>0` with `a` being the roundoff error; for example `a=2*eps`.

Answer (score 2):

the find command in matlab solves this. try:

if `a = [0 0 0 2 3 4 2 0 0 0];` then

```
a(find(a==0))=[];
```

or

```
a(a==0)=[];
```

removes the zeros without for loop

Answer (score 1):

"Logical indexing" is the most efficient way to do something like this.

```
dataWithoutZeros = data(data ~= 0);
```

This is because in addition to the usual way of indexing matrices in MATLAB, by specifying a set of index positions, you can also specify an array of `logical` values of the same dimension as the array

```
data = [10 20 30 40];
a = data([1 3]); % a has value [10 30]
b = data(logical([1 0 1 0])); % b has the same value as a
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to cut off the leading and trailing zeroes, you will need a solution that does not get rid of the middle zeroes. In this case I would suggest the following:

```
x = [ 0 0 1 2 0 -3 0]
x(find(x,1,'first'):find(x,1,'last'))
```

Will give:

```
1     2     0    -3
```

---

If you are worried about precision, try this:

```
x = [ 0 0 1 2 0 -3 0]
idx = abs(x)>1e-12
x(find(idx,1,'first'):find(idx,1,'last'))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this means:                               x(find(x,1,'first'):find(x,1,'last'))

Comment: I haven't used the find function before

Comment: @vdhalla `find(x,1,'first')` does this: it `find`s exactly `1` element that is not zero, namely the `first`. So basically my second solution finds the first and last element that is not (nearly) zero, and gives you all `x` values between - and including - them. Also try `help find` if you want a more detailled explanation on `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Or even, for less effort at the fingertips and arguably less comprehensible, take advantage of a language which thinks that `0` is the same as `not true` ...

```
myvector(find(myvector))
```

returns just the non `0` elements of `myvector`.